Nouveau works but NVIDIA buggy with 3 monitor (2 Philips and 1 TCL) system
The NVIDIA driver is buggy in to ways compared to the Nouveau driver:

It restricts my TCL display to 1920w (all monitors support 3840w)
The below-pictured arrangement of displays frequently reverts the the one pictured at this askubuntu question -- usually after the inactive timeout and password entry to reactivate. Arrangements where the screens do not reflect their physical arrangement, but rather are set side by side don't seem affected.


With the nouveau driver active:
$ uname -a
Linux jaboweryML 6.5.0-28-generic #29~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Thu Apr  4 14:39:20 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ sudo lshw -class display
[sudo] password for jabowery: 
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: GA104 [GeForce RTX 3070 Ti]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:09:00.0
       logical name: /dev/fb0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom fb
       configuration: depth=32 driver=nouveau latency=0 resolution=3840,2160
       resources: irq:108 memory:fb000000-fbffffff memory:d0000000-dfffffff memory:e0000000-e1ffffff ioport:e000(size=128) memory:c0000-dffff

 $ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 16 x 16, current 7680 x 4320, maximum 32767 x 32767

XWAYLAND0 connected 3840x2160+2023+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 1110mm x 620mm
   3840x2160     29.98*+
   2048x1536     29.95  
...
XWAYLAND1 connected primary 3840x2160+3840+2160 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 600mm x 340mm
   3840x2160     59.98*+
   2048x1536     59.95  
...
XWAYLAND2 connected 3840x2160+0+2160 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 600mm x 340mm
   3840x2160     59.98*+
   2048x1536     59.95  
...

$ sudo dmesg | grep -iE "drm|display"
[    0.000000] Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-6.5.0-28-generic root=UUID=57cf3490-db84-4071-8c09-ceb97e4bc676 ro nvidia-drm.modeset=1
[    0.124437] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-6.5.0-28-generic root=UUID=57cf3490-db84-4071-8c09-ceb97e4bc676 ro nvidia-drm.modeset=1
[    2.500157] systemd[1]: Starting Load Kernel Module drm...
[    2.523083] ACPI: bus type drm_connector registered
[    2.528328] systemd[1]: modprobe@drm.service: Deactivated successfully.
[    2.528976] systemd[1]: Finished Load Kernel Module drm.
[    2.546654] evdi evdi.0: [drm] Cannot find any crtc or sizes
[    2.547152] [drm] Initialized evdi 1.14.4 20240410 for evdi.0 on minor 0
[    2.547210] evdi evdi.1: [drm] Cannot find any crtc or sizes
[    2.547330] [drm] Initialized evdi 1.14.4 20240410 for evdi.1 on minor 1
[    2.547381] evdi evdi.2: [drm] Cannot find any crtc or sizes
[    2.547538] [drm] Initialized evdi 1.14.4 20240410 for evdi.2 on minor 2
[    2.551746] evdi evdi.3: [drm] Cannot find any crtc or sizes
[    2.552219] [drm] Initialized evdi 1.14.4 20240410 for evdi.3 on minor 3
[    3.247232] nouveau 0000:09:00.0: DRM: VRAM: 8192 MiB
[    3.247237] nouveau 0000:09:00.0: DRM: GART: 536870912 MiB
[    3.247240] nouveau 0000:09:00.0: DRM: BIT table 'A' not found
[    3.247242] nouveau 0000:09:00.0: DRM: BIT table 'L' not found
[    3.247244] nouveau 0000:09:00.0: DRM: TMDS table version 2.0
[    3.247247] nouveau 0000:09:00.0: DRM: DCB version 4.1
[    3.247250] nouveau 0000:09:00.0: DRM: DCB outp 00: 04800f86 04600020
[    3.247253] nouveau 0000:09:00.0: DRM: DCB outp 01: 04000f82 00020020
[    3.247255] nouveau 0000:09:00.0: DRM: DCB outp 02: 04811f76 04600010
[    3.247258] nouveau 0000:09:00.0: DRM: DCB outp 03: 04011f72 00020010
[    3.247260] nouveau 0000:09:00.0: DRM: DCB outp 04: 02822f66 04600020
[    3.247262] nouveau 0000:09:00.0: DRM: DCB outp 05: 02022f62 00020020
[    3.247265] nouveau 0000:09:00.0: DRM: DCB outp 07: 02033f52 00020010
[    3.247267] nouveau 0000:09:00.0: DRM: DCB conn 00: 02000046
[    3.247269] nouveau 0000:09:00.0: DRM: DCB conn 01: 01000146
[    3.247271] nouveau 0000:09:00.0: DRM: DCB conn 02: 00020246
[    3.247273] nouveau 0000:09:00.0: DRM: DCB conn 03: 00010361
[    3.247983] nouveau 0000:09:00.0: DRM: MM: using COPY for buffer copies
[    3.251558] [drm] Initialized nouveau 1.3.1 20120801 for 0000:09:00.0 on minor 4
[    3.919154] fbcon: nouveaudrmfb (fb0) is primary device
[    4.774965] nouveau 0000:09:00.0: [drm] fb0: nouveaudrmfb frame buffer device
[    6.968525] workqueue: drm_fb_helper_damage_work [drm_kms_helper] hogged CPU for >10000us 4 times, consider switching to WQ_UNBOUND
[    8.648527] workqueue: output_poll_execute [drm_kms_helper] hogged CPU for >10000us 4 times, consider switching to WQ_UNBOUND

After switching to the nvidia driver (tested) these commands yielded the following:
$ nvidia-smi
Wed May  1 16:57:33 2024       
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 535.171.04             Driver Version: 535.171.04   CUDA Version: 12.2     |
|-----------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name                 Persistence-M | Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp   Perf          Pwr:Usage/Cap |         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                                         |                      |               MIG M. |
|=========================================+======================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3070 Ti     Off | 00000000:09:00.0  On |                  N/A |
| 30%   41C    P3              48W / 290W |    945MiB /  8192MiB |      1%      Default |
|                                         |                      |                  N/A |
+-----------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                                         
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                            |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                            GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                             Usage      |
|=======================================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A      3800      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell                        941MiB |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
$ dpkg -l | grep ^ii.*nvidia
ii  libnvidia-cfg1-535:amd64                         535.171.04-0ubuntu0.22.04.1                                     amd64        NVIDIA binary OpenGL/GLX configuration library
ii  libnvidia-common-535                             535.171.04-0ubuntu0.22.04.1                                     all          Shared files used by the NVIDIA libraries
ii  libnvidia-compute-535:amd64                      535.171.04-0ubuntu0.22.04.1                                     amd64        NVIDIA libcompute package
ii  libnvidia-compute-535:i386                       535.171.04-0ubuntu0.22.04.1                                     i386         NVIDIA libcompute package
ii  libnvidia-decode-535:amd64                       535.171.04-0ubuntu0.22.04.1                                     amd64        NVIDIA Video Decoding runtime libraries
ii  libnvidia-decode-535:i386                        535.171.04-0ubuntu0.22.04.1                                     i386         NVIDIA Video Decoding runtime libraries
ii  libnvidia-encode-535:amd64                       535.171.04-0ubuntu0.22.04.1                                     amd64        NVENC Video Encoding runtime library
ii  libnvidia-encode-535:i386                        535.171.04-0ubuntu0.22.04.1                                     i386         NVENC Video Encoding runtime library
ii  libnvidia-extra-535:amd64                        535.171.04-0ubuntu0.22.04.1                                     amd64        Extra libraries for the NVIDIA driver
ii  libnvidia-fbc1-535:amd64                         535.171.04-0ubuntu0.22.04.1                                     amd64        NVIDIA OpenGL-based Framebuffer Capture runtime library
ii  libnvidia-fbc1-535:i386                          535.171.04-0ubuntu0.22.04.1                                     i386         NVIDIA OpenGL-based Framebuffer Capture runtime library
ii  libnvidia-gl-535:amd64                           535.171.04-0ubuntu0.22.04.1                                     amd64        NVIDIA OpenGL/GLX/EGL/GLES GLVND libraries and Vulkan ICD
ii  libnvidia-gl-535:i386                            535.171.04-0ubuntu0.22.04.1                                     i386         NVIDIA OpenGL/GLX/EGL/GLES GLVND libraries and Vulkan ICD
ii  linux-modules-nvidia-535-6.5.0-28-generic        6.5.0-28.29~22.04.1+2                                           amd64        Linux kernel nvidia modules for version 6.5.0-28
ii  linux-modules-nvidia-535-generic-hwe-22.04       6.5.0-28.29~22.04.1+2                                           amd64        Extra drivers for nvidia-535 for the generic-hwe-22.04 flavour
ii  linux-objects-nvidia-535-6.5.0-28-generic        6.5.0-28.29~22.04.1+2                                           amd64        Linux kernel nvidia modules for version 6.5.0-28 (objects)
ii  linux-objects-nvidia-535-server-6.5.0-28-generic 6.5.0-28.29~22.04.1+2                                           amd64        Linux kernel nvidia modules for version 6.5.0-28 (objects)
ii  linux-objects-nvidia-545-6.5.0-28-generic        6.5.0-28.29~22.04.1+2                                           amd64        Linux kernel nvidia modules for version 6.5.0-28 (objects)
ii  linux-signatures-nvidia-6.5.0-28-generic         6.5.0-28.29~22.04.1+2                                           amd64        Linux kernel signatures for nvidia modules for version 6.5.0-28-generic
ii  nvidia-compute-utils-535                         535.171.04-0ubuntu0.22.04.1                                     amd64        NVIDIA compute utilities
ii  nvidia-driver-535                                535.171.04-0ubuntu0.22.04.1                                     amd64        NVIDIA driver metapackage
ii  nvidia-firmware-535-535.171.04                   535.171.04-0ubuntu0.22.04.1                                     amd64        Firmware files used by the kernel module
ii  nvidia-kernel-common-535                         535.171.04-0ubuntu0.22.04.1                                     amd64        Shared files used with the kernel module
ii  nvidia-kernel-source-535                         535.171.04-0ubuntu0.22.04.1                                     amd64        NVIDIA kernel source package
ii  nvidia-prime                                     0.8.17.1                                                        all          Tools to enable NVIDIA's Prime
ii  nvidia-settings                                  510.47.03-0ubuntu1                                              amd64        Tool for configuring the NVIDIA graphics driver
ii  nvidia-utils-535                                 535.171.04-0ubuntu0.22.04.1                                     amd64        NVIDIA driver support binaries
ii  screen-resolution-extra                          0.18.2                                                          all          Extension for the nvidia-settings control panel
ii  xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-535                    535.171.04-0ubuntu0.22.04.1                            
$ dpkg -l | grep ^ii.*nvidia|grep -v 535.171.04
ii  linux-modules-nvidia-535-6.5.0-28-generic        6.5.0-28.29~22.04.1+2                                           amd64        Linux kernel nvidia modules for version 6.5.0-28
ii  linux-modules-nvidia-535-generic-hwe-22.04       6.5.0-28.29~22.04.1+2                                           amd64        Extra drivers for nvidia-535 for the generic-hwe-22.04 flavour
ii  linux-objects-nvidia-535-6.5.0-28-generic        6.5.0-28.29~22.04.1+2                                           amd64        Linux kernel nvidia modules for version 6.5.0-28 (objects)
ii  linux-objects-nvidia-535-server-6.5.0-28-generic 6.5.0-28.29~22.04.1+2                                           amd64        Linux kernel nvidia modules for version 6.5.0-28 (objects)
ii  linux-objects-nvidia-545-6.5.0-28-generic        6.5.0-28.29~22.04.1+2                                           amd64        Linux kernel nvidia modules for version 6.5.0-28 (objects)
ii  linux-signatures-nvidia-6.5.0-28-generic         6.5.0-28.29~22.04.1+2                                           amd64        Linux kernel signatures for nvidia modules for version 6.5.0-28-generic
ii  nvidia-prime                                     0.8.17.1                                                        all          Tools to enable NVIDIA's Prime
ii  nvidia-settings                                  510.47.03-0ubuntu1                                              amd64        Tool for configuring the NVIDIA graphics driver
ii  screen-resolution-extra                          0.18.2                                                          all          Extension for the nvidia-settings control panel

Switching to 545.29.06 and rebooting yields:
$ nvidia-smi
Thu May  2 14:32:29 2024       
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 545.29.06              Driver Version: 545.29.06    CUDA Version: 12.3     |
|-----------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name                 Persistence-M | Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp   Perf          Pwr:Usage/Cap |         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                                         |                      |               MIG M. |
|=========================================+======================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3070 Ti     Off | 00000000:09:00.0  On |                  N/A |
| 30%   40C    P3              48W / 290W |   1601MiB /  8192MiB |      9%      Default |
|                                         |                      |                  N/A |
+-----------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                                         
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                            |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                            GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                             Usage      |
|=======================================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A      3551      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                          846MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      3890      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell                        204MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      6659      G   gnome-control-center                         43MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      7084      G   ...,262144 --variations-seed-version=1      494MiB |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
$ dpkg -l | grep ^ii.*nvidia
ii  libnvidia-cfg1-545:amd64                         545.29.06-0ubuntu0.22.04.2                                      amd64        NVIDIA binary OpenGL/GLX configuration library
ii  libnvidia-common-545                             545.29.06-0ubuntu0.22.04.2                                      all          Shared files used by the NVIDIA libraries
ii  libnvidia-compute-545:amd64                      545.29.06-0ubuntu0.22.04.2                                      amd64        NVIDIA libcompute package
ii  libnvidia-compute-545:i386                       545.29.06-0ubuntu0.22.04.2                                      i386         NVIDIA libcompute package
ii  libnvidia-decode-545:amd64                       545.29.06-0ubuntu0.22.04.2                                      amd64        NVIDIA Video Decoding runtime libraries
ii  libnvidia-decode-545:i386                        545.29.06-0ubuntu0.22.04.2                                      i386         NVIDIA Video Decoding runtime libraries
ii  libnvidia-encode-545:amd64                       545.29.06-0ubuntu0.22.04.2                                      amd64        NVENC Video Encoding runtime library
ii  libnvidia-encode-545:i386                        545.29.06-0ubuntu0.22.04.2                                      i386         NVENC Video Encoding runtime library
ii  libnvidia-extra-545:amd64                        545.29.06-0ubuntu0.22.04.2                                      amd64        Extra libraries for the NVIDIA driver
ii  libnvidia-fbc1-545:amd64                         545.29.06-0ubuntu0.22.04.2                                      amd64        NVIDIA OpenGL-based Framebuffer Capture runtime library
ii  libnvidia-fbc1-545:i386                          545.29.06-0ubuntu0.22.04.2                                      i386         NVIDIA OpenGL-based Framebuffer Capture runtime library
ii  libnvidia-gl-545:amd64                           545.29.06-0ubuntu0.22.04.2                                      amd64        NVIDIA OpenGL/GLX/EGL/GLES GLVND libraries and Vulkan ICD
ii  libnvidia-gl-545:i386                            545.29.06-0ubuntu0.22.04.2                                      i386         NVIDIA OpenGL/GLX/EGL/GLES GLVND libraries and Vulkan ICD
ii  linux-modules-nvidia-545-6.5.0-28-generic        6.5.0-28.29~22.04.1+2                                           amd64        Linux kernel nvidia modules for version 6.5.0-28
ii  linux-modules-nvidia-545-generic-hwe-22.04       6.5.0-28.29~22.04.1+2                                           amd64        Extra drivers for nvidia-545 for the generic-hwe-22.04 flavour
ii  linux-objects-nvidia-535-6.5.0-28-generic        6.5.0-28.29~22.04.1+2                                           amd64        Linux kernel nvidia modules for version 6.5.0-28 (objects)
ii  linux-objects-nvidia-535-server-6.5.0-28-generic 6.5.0-28.29~22.04.1+2                                           amd64        Linux kernel nvidia modules for version 6.5.0-28 (objects)
ii  linux-objects-nvidia-545-6.5.0-28-generic        6.5.0-28.29~22.04.1+2                                           amd64        Linux kernel nvidia modules for version 6.5.0-28 (objects)
ii  linux-signatures-nvidia-6.5.0-28-generic         6.5.0-28.29~22.04.1+2                                           amd64        Linux kernel signatures for nvidia modules for version 6.5.0-28-generic
ii  nvidia-compute-utils-545                         545.29.06-0ubuntu0.22.04.2                                      amd64        NVIDIA compute utilities
ii  nvidia-driver-545                                545.29.06-0ubuntu0.22.04.2                                      amd64        NVIDIA driver metapackage
ii  nvidia-firmware-545-545.29.06                    545.29.06-0ubuntu0.22.04.2                                      amd64        Firmware files used by the kernel module
ii  nvidia-kernel-common-545                         545.29.06-0ubuntu0.22.04.2                                      amd64        Shared files used with the kernel module
ii  nvidia-kernel-source-545                         545.29.06-0ubuntu0.22.04.2                                      amd64        NVIDIA kernel source package
ii  nvidia-prime                                     0.8.17.1                                                        all          Tools to enable NVIDIA's Prime
ii  nvidia-settings                                  510.47.03-0ubuntu1                                              amd64        Tool for configuring the NVIDIA graphics driver
ii  nvidia-utils-545                                 545.29.06-0ubuntu0.22.04.2                                      amd64        NVIDIA driver support binaries
ii  screen-resolution-extra                          0.18.2                                                          all          Extension for the nvidia-settings control panel
ii  xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-545                    545.29.06-0ubuntu0.22.04.2                                      amd64        NVIDIA binary Xorg driver
$ dpkg -l | grep ^ii.*nvidia|grep -v 545.29.06
ii  linux-modules-nvidia-545-6.5.0-28-generic        6.5.0-28.29~22.04.1+2                                           amd64        Linux kernel nvidia modules for version 6.5.0-28
ii  linux-modules-nvidia-545-generic-hwe-22.04       6.5.0-28.29~22.04.1+2                                           amd64        Extra drivers for nvidia-545 for the generic-hwe-22.04 flavour
ii  linux-objects-nvidia-535-6.5.0-28-generic        6.5.0-28.29~22.04.1+2                                           amd64        Linux kernel nvidia modules for version 6.5.0-28 (objects)
ii  linux-objects-nvidia-535-server-6.5.0-28-generic 6.5.0-28.29~22.04.1+2                                           amd64        Linux kernel nvidia modules for version 6.5.0-28 (objects)
ii  linux-objects-nvidia-545-6.5.0-28-generic        6.5.0-28.29~22.04.1+2                                           amd64        Linux kernel nvidia modules for version 6.5.0-28 (objects)
ii  linux-signatures-nvidia-6.5.0-28-generic         6.5.0-28.29~22.04.1+2                                           amd64        Linux kernel signatures for nvidia modules for version 6.5.0-28-generic
ii  nvidia-prime                                     0.8.17.1                                                        all          Tools to enable NVIDIA's Prime
ii  nvidia-settings                                  510.47.03-0ubuntu1                                              amd64        Tool for configuring the NVIDIA graphics driver
ii  screen-resolution-extra                          0.18.2                                                          all          Extension for the nvidia-settings control panel


$ nvidia-smi <- please run that and add the output to your posting. In similar manner, verify that you have all main parts on the driver from the same version: $ dpkg -l | grep ^ii.*nvidia lists the installed ones (due to ^ii ) you may then append | grep -v main.version.number  with numbers replacing the last three words, to display the packages not matching the version.

For what it is worth: I have just today "remedied" a gdm3 crash by first purging it, then reinstralling gdm3 and gdm3-settings and additionally jumping from nvidia 535, to 470, to nouveau and then back to 535 - which is currently there, working.

I've added the nvidia-related diagnostics output.

Well, that did only reveal that you use the very same driver as I do (on my latop w 1660 Ti). Maybe try other version of driver? hit Win-key and the type driver to see a greenish icon, click it and select other driver version, try a reboot as it has finished it's job.

Switching to 545.29.06 does not fix the bug.  Upon bootup there were just two monitors (as frequently happens #1 was not active).  Turning off monitors #2 and #3 and turning on #1 with Apply caused it to reset to the desired configuration (2 at the top with 1 and 3 both working) so that "Keep settings" returned to the desired configuration.  This is typical behavior of the bug.

Seen elsewhere: (24.04 has known problems with 545 and 550 drivers).

This problem with screen geometry has been going on for years.
